# Почему не видны jars sockjs и stomp?

Tags: java, websocket, sockjs, spring-websocket

В Maven они видны. Он на них не ругается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в браузере пишет, что их нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои зависимости

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки:

```
package com.example.socialnetwork.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
package com.example.socialnetwork.controllers;

import com.example.socialnetwork.models.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @GetMapping("/chat")
    public String showChat() {
        return "chat";
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public Message send(Message message) throws Exception {
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
        return message;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
'use strict';

let stompClient = null;

function setConnected(connected) {
    document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
    document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
    document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility
        = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
}

function connect() {
    let socket = new SockJS('/chat');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function(messageOutput) {
            showMessageOutput(JSON.parse(messageOutput.body));
        });
    });
}

function disconnect() {
    if(stompClient != null) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendMessage() {
    let from = document.getElementById('from').value;
    let text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    stompClient.send("/app/chat", {}, JSON.stringify({'from':from, 'text':text}));
}

function showMessageOutput(messageOutput) {
    let response = document.getElementById('response');
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(messageOutput.from + ": "
        + messageOutput.text + " (" + messageOutput.time + ")"));
    response.appendChild(p);
}
```

И html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chat WebSocket</title>
    <script src="/webjars/sockjs-client/1.1.2/sockjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/webjars/stomp-websocket/2.3.3/stomp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/chat-app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body onload="disconnect()">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="from" placeholder="Choose a nickname"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
            <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">
                Disconnect
            </button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="conversationDiv">
            <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Write a message..."/>
            <button id="sendMessage" onclick="sendMessage();">Send</button>
            <p id="response"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Используется голый Spring?

Comment: @OlegMarchenko, нет, используются Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring Security

Comment: а какие настройки [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc) , если это не springboot? для springboot другой [пример](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: @MrFylypenko, как раз таки Spring Boot используется

Comment: тогда в зависимостях должна быть зависимость `webjars-locator-core` , а ссылка на ресурс: `<script src="/webjars/stomp-websocket/stomp.min.js"></script>`, это из [этого примера](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: @MrFylypenko, Всё так прописано, зависимости все есть, но всё равно не срабатывает

Comment: пробовали прописать ссылку на ресурсы без версии, вот так: `<script src="/webjars/stomp-websocket/stomp.js"></script>` ? или чуть выше с `min` ? без версии рекомендуется указывать [в документации](https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springboot) и в примере который указал выше

Comment: @MrFylypenko, да, так тоже пробовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После тщетных попыток указывания пути к jar-кам, я прописал ссылку на библиотеки и всё сработало. Странно, что сработало именно сейчас, ведь раньше я тоже пытался прописат прямую ссылку на библиотеки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]